# IE7 Image Padding

Tags: jquery, image, padding, internet-explorer-7

I have a simple function which attempts to calculate height and width of an image using jQuery for a slideshow box. The problem I am seeing in IE7 is the really strange effects padding seem to have on width/height.

I have an image in Firefox and value returned is 450 x 324 [width / height] with CSS values of

```
border:0 none;
float:right;
padding:20px 10px 30px 10px;
width:450px;
```

In IE7, it gives me a width of 470 and height of 374 ? How to do I calc the "real" values ?

Comment: Don't forget to mark an answer as correct, or clarify your question if the answer wasn't what you were looking for.

Answer (score 1):

IE's old box model (aka quirks mode) included padding in the width & height, the W3C box model (aka standards mode) does not.

If you use an xhtml or html5 doctype, IE7 will render in standards mode and this will no longer be a problem.